# Cloud Business App for Office 365

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, office-365, visual-studio-2013, cloud-business-apps

I try to create Business App for SP Online. If I create relationship to other list in the same site, everything is OK. I can use lookup field. But if I try to use relationship (data) from different localization I've got an error:

> An error occurred while processing this request. Inner exception
>   message:     Request
>   Error BODY { color: #000000; background-color: white;
>   font-family: Verdana; margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px; } #content {
>   margin-left: 30px; font-size: .70em; padding-bottom: 2em; } A:link {
>   color: #336699; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; }
>   A:visited { color: #6699cc; font-weight: bold; text-decoration:
>   underline; } A:active { color: #336699; font-weight: bold;
>   text-decoration: underline; } .heading1 { background-color: #003366;
>   border-bottom: #336699 6px solid; color: #ffffff; font-family: Tahoma;
>   font-size: 26px; font-weight: normal;margin: 0em 0em 10px -20px;
>   padding-bottom: 8px; padding-left: 30px;padding-top: 16px;} pre {
>   font-size:small; background-color: #e5e5cc; padding: 5px; font-family:
>   Courier New; margin-top: 0px; border: 1px #f0f0e0 solid; white-space:
>   pre-wrap; white-space: -pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word; } table {
>   border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0px; font-family: Verdana;}
>   table th { border-right: 2px white solid; border-bottom: 2px white
>   solid; font-weight: bold; background-color: #cecf9c;} table td {
>   border-right: 2px white solid; border-bottom: 2px white solid;
>   background-color: #e5e5cc;}   
>   Request Error
>
> The server encountered an
>   error processing the request. See server logs for more details.

I have base on this video [How Do I: Build and Deploy My First Cloud Business App on Office 365?](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/CBA/How-Do-I-Build-and-Deploy-My-First-Cloud-Business-App-on-Office-365-)

Have you met a similar problem?